# In Swift, why don't I have to always return the types that are expected as shown in the reference docs?

Tags: ios, swift, return-type

While repeatedly working on tutorials to learn Swift, I noticed that methods such as `UITableViewDataSource's` `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` requires that we return a type of UITableViewCell which I've implemented numerous times however for methods such as NSSpeechSynthesizer's `startSpeaking(_:)` I was able to call this method without returning the expected boolean.  What am I not understanding or why is that?

```
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var speakButton: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopButton: NSButton!

    let speechSynth = NSSpeechSynthesizer()

    override var windowNibName: NSNib.Name? {
        return NSNib.Name("MainWindowController")
    }

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

    }

    // MARK: - Action methods
    @IBAction func speakIt(sender: NSButton) {

        //Get tuype-in text as a strin
        let string = textField.stringValue
        if string.isEmpty {
            print("string from \(textField) is empty")
        } else {
            speechSynth.startSpeaking(string)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func stopIt(sender: NSButton) {
        speechSynth.stopSpeaking()
    }
}
```

Comment: Ummm... you're calling the function, not implementing it. Not using the returned value is totally optional, and that's a general programming thing, not related to Swift.
Swift just warns you if you don't use returned stuff. 
I'd delete this question and look up something like "Do I have to use returned values" or similar

Comment: @StephenJ I appreciate your suggestion.  So basically you're saying that I could use the returned value which is a boolean by declaring this function with a variable?  For example let spokenWord = speechSynth.startSpeaking(string)

Comment: Yes... this is basic programming. Try cprogramming.com 's tutorial. Functions that return values help for later verification, but often aren't needed. Swift is unfortunately hyper-strict, and as a first language, is a terrible introduction to programming. Void pointers should be your friend, and you should be responsible enough to handle them.
But anyway, I suggested deletion 'cause I knew you'd be downvoted. Don't take it to heart, everyone needs to learn! Just, I highly recommend learning at cprogramming for your first foray into languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startSpeaking` does return a `Bool`. You are choosing to not use that return value. And you didn't actually implement the `startSpeaking` method so you are not the one that has to return anything. As the caller, you choose to make use of the return value or not.

You could write:

```
if speechSynth.startSpeaking(string) == false {
    // Uh oh, it didn't start speaking
}
```

Another way to look at this - there is a big difference between *implementing* a method and *calling* a method. Your example with the table view data source method is one that you are *implementing*. Calling `startSpeaking` is an example of *calling* a method.

Comment: would the startSpeaking() method ever return false if the parameter is fulfilled with a string?  If so, could you provide an example like you did above?

Comment: I have no idea under what conditions `startSpeaking` might return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You call `startSpeaking` with a string (Here you're a **Sender** in parameter **Receiver** in return )

```
func startSpeaking(_ string: String) -> Bool // feedback from system
```

and expect the system to return a true / false

but in ( Here you're a **Sender** in return **Receiver** in parameter )

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
 cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  // feedback to system
```

you provide the system (Tableview) with the content that he must show when you implement the tableView

Comment: so basically in the startSpeaking example I'm the sender because I was using an instance of the class versus in tableViewCellForRow I'm actually creating what's going to be sent back to an instance that calls this method.  Right?